# Adding pagination in PDO

Tags: php, pagination

I am learning **PDO.**

Can anyone help me to add  pagination in this code?

I would be glad if someone shows me 10/50/100 table row at a time.

```
    public function getService(){
        global $pdo;
        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `pservice`");
        $query->execute();
        return $query->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } 

    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($result); $i++)
       {
        echo "<tr>".
        "<td>".($i+1)."</td>".
        "<td>".$result[$i]["pname"]."</td>".
        "<td>".$result[$i]["date"]."</td>".
        "<td>".$result[$i]["ecg"]."</td>".
        "<td>".$result[$i]["eco"]."</td>".
        "<td>".$result[$i]["ecodoppler"]."</td>".
        "<td>".$result[$i]["consultationfee"]."</td>".
        "<td>".$result[$i]["assesmentfee"]."</td>".
        "<td>".$result[$i]["regfee"]."</td>".
        "<td>".$result[$i]["consultby"]."</td>".                      
      "</tr>";
      }
```

Comment: check this post http://code.runnable.com/VSpZzVic6P4hfniR/php-pdo-pagination-example-for-mysql

Comment: @nazmul use an external library such as http://datatables.net/ this will help you for pagination

Answer (score 0):

Don't just copy it make changes as per your requirement, if its only adding pagination then this library might help you:

Use [Data Tables](http://datatables.net/)

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="users">
        <thead>
          <tr>


            <th>P Name</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>ECG</th>
            <th>ECO</th>
            <th>ECO Doppler</th>
            //So On..



          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

?>
<?php 
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($result); $i++)
       {
        echo "<tr>".
        "<td>".($i+1)."</td>".
        "<td>".$result[$i]["pname"]."</td>".
        "<td>".$result[$i]["date"]."</td>".
        "<td>".$result[$i]["ecg"]."</td>".
        "<td>".$result[$i]["eco"]."</td>".
        "<td>".$result[$i]["ecodoppler"]."</td>".
        "<td>".$result[$i]["consultationfee"]."</td>".
        "<td>".$result[$i]["assesmentfee"]."</td>".
        "<td>".$result[$i]["regfee"]."</td>".
        "<td>".$result[$i]["consultby"]."</td>".                      
      "</tr>";
      }

      ?>
```

Then a script that initializes your tables :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#users').DataTable( {
    responsive: true
} );
</script>
```

And Use these CSS and JS:

```
//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css
//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
```